# arcpy pydev 3rd party toolbox intellisense

Tags: arcpy

I am just newly started to look at arcpy and i see that it has good intellisense for system toolboxes by default and also if you import a custom toolbox - the intellisense gets update also - however this seems to only work in arcgis built-in python.

i am trying to setup this in pydev/eclipse - but even though i imported my toolbox stll pydev cannot recognise

toolsNameError: name 'Mytool' is not defined

but if you run it works fine. - i just want to work in pydev and to be able to see the custom tool references also ?

anybody can help

thanks

MJ

Comment: See [these questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=pydev) on GIS.se as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the ESRI all the ArcPy locations in the list in Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter - Python.   If that doesn't work then add the Arc installation of Python in your interpreter list (same location - but the box above) and specify that for this project.